# PHP Soap handshake failure

Tags: php, web-services, ssl, soap

I've got this problem:

I'm using a Web Service with PHP soap. Everything works fine on my localhost, but when I put it on the remote server I get this error:

```
SoapClient::SoapClient(): SSL operation failed with code 1. 
OpenSSL Error messages: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Remote server is running on HTTPS. Remote server uses PHP 5.3 and on localhost PHP 5.5. Does anybody know why it works on localhost and not on the remote server? And if so, how can I fix this problem? I already read more than 10 questions but none of them worked and 60% of them were for JAVA and not for PHP. I will greatly appreciate any kind of help, because I'm trying to get this fixed more than 3 whole days. This is how I call Web Service:

```
$wsdl_url = 'https://somehost.com/someWebservice.wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url, array('login' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'trace' => true));
```

EDIT: I'm using another 3 Web Services on my remote server and they work fine. That's one more reason why I don't have any clue why this one doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So ive already fixed the problem with handshake failure. It was due to php version. As soon as i upgraded to php 5.5 it solved the problem.